# How do I re run failed Cucumber scenarios from Maven?

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng

I am trying to re run my failed cucumber tests. I use maven and TestNG in my framework. How can I achieve this?

I have tried maven-surefire-plugin (version: 3.0.0-M3) in my POM with `<rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>`. But this does not rerun the test automatically when a test fails.

POM snippet

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M3</version>
<configuration>
<!-- <suiteXmlFiles>testNG.xml</suiteXmlFiles> -->
<classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
<skipTests>false</skipTests>
<!-- <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> -->
<testSourceDirectory>/src/test/java/testRunners</testSourceDirectory>
<useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
<rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>  
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Runner class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/java/features",
glue= {"stepDefinitions"},  
tags= {"@licensing01"},
dryRun = false,
plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:TestExecutionReports/TestResults.html"
+ ",rerun:TestExecutionReports/failed_scenarios.txt"
+ ",json:target/cucumber.json"},
monochrome = true
)

public class TestRunnerBAU extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
}
```

I expect the failed tests to be rerun automatically. But currently the failed tests are not rerun.

Answer (score 2):

### As Per Maven Guideline

> This feature is supported only for **JUnit 4.x** (Not **TestNG**)

Since of **2.21.0** the provider **surefire-junit47** can rerun scenarios created by **cucumber-jvm 2.0.0 and higher**.

**Source :** https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html